# Excel VBA Pivot chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts, pivot

I am trying to write a macro for creating a pivot chart. In a sheet in column D I have the list of users. One username can be number of time in column D. I'm trying to find out % of each username from the overall usercount

I need to draw a column chart, user in X axis and % in Y axis. The chart should start after 3 rows of the last cell in column D. The number of rows in column D will vary every time depending on the sample rate. I am trying this to automate some of the test results.

The code I tried

```
lastTC = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastTCP = lastTC + 3
lastTCP1 = lastTC + 10
lastTCC = lastTC + 18

lastTC = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D1", "D" & lastTC).Select
 ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    ("TOPMEM!$D$1:$D" & lastTC), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:=("TOPMEM!R1C10"), TableName:="PivotTable5", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

Sheets("TOPMEM").Select
Cells(724, 1).Select
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("USER")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable5").PivotFields("USER"), "Count of USER", xlCount

Range("K1").Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("Count of USER")
    .Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End With
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
```

Comment: What problem are you having. Does it not compile? Not run? If it does both, what issues are you trying to solve?

Comment: I get "Run Time Error - 1004 Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class".

Answer (score 0):

Your pivot table name must be incorrect. Right click on your pivot table and select Pivot Table Options from the context menu. Check the pivot table name at the top of the popup window.

In addition, use code like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim p As PivotTable
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Set s = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
    Set p = s.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
End Sub
```

It is more robust and easier to debug. If you click on a different sheet while the macro is running, it will fail. With the above code, this would not happen. Avoid ActiveSheet and ActiveWorkbook in general.